Ceiling Fan/Light Wiring
I am working on finishing up the wiring at my house. I have 2 ceiling fans in my downstairs living room, I initially wired them up in hopes to be able to turn them on when walking in from the main door, walking in from the garage, and also when I am upstairs. So 3 spots total.
I wired them with 14/2 Line coming into the initial box (near garage door), from there I ran 14/3 to the first ceiling fan, then to the 2nd ceiling fan, then to the middle box (near main door), and from there to the end box (upstairs).
My plan is to use a 3-way combination rocker switch at the initial box, the other 3-way combination rocker switch will be at the end box, and then in the middle, there will be a single-pole 4-way rocker switch.
Is that going to be plausible? My understanding is that the 4-way will essentially only be a switch leg (be it lights and fan or just one or the other), and the 3-way combinations will be able to dictate if I have both the fans and the lights on or just one or the other.
I am by no means an electrician so I am asking for thoughts before attempting.
Thank you in advance!

As indicated by the answers, your setup is feasible. It creates 3 locations at which you can turn on both fans (and any lights in them), or turn off both fans (and any lights in them). If you want to have other possibilities, like at each location choosing what to turn on/off, then you need more switches and a more complicated wiring setup.

There are some variations, particularly in older wiring. But the general concept is as follows, assuming only 14 AWG (15A) needed. If it is a 20A circuit then just change 14/2 and 14/3 to 12/2 and 12/3.

Panel to first switch: 14/2
First switch (3-way) to second switch (4-way): 14/3
Second switch (4-way) to third switch (3-way): 14/3
Third switch (3-way) to fan: 14/2

It is possible to make use of a junction box with a fan in between the switches. However, additional wires (more practically, additional cables) are needed in order to do this. 14/2 and 14/3 cables are, relatively speaking, cheap and easy. Bigger cables (14/4 or even 14/5) are possible but get more expensive.
In this particular setup, I would do one of the following:
Finish current setup

Panel to first switch 14/2 (done)
First switch to first fan 14/3 (done) - but this will only pass through, not connect to the fan.
First fan to second fan 14/3 (done) - but this will only pass through, not connect to the fan.
Second fan to second switch 14/3 (done)
Second switch to third switch 14/3 (done)

But then you add:

Third switch to second fan 14/2
Second fan to first fan 14/2

Switches then Fans

Panel to first switch 14/2 (done)
Second switch to third switch 14/3 (done)
Third switch to second fan 14/2 but you can use the existing 14/3 and cap one wire
Second fan to first fan 14/2 but you can use the existing 14/3 and cap one wire

But then you add:

First switch to second switch 14/3

and abandon the cable from the first switch to the first fan.
If, for example, the wiring between switches and fans is in a finished ceiling and hard to access, then the second method may be easier, even though it requires running a cable between switches.
However, if it is easy to add additional cables along some sections that already have cables then the first method will be easier.

If you are doing all this new in 2024, you could do it in other ways that do not require special high-voltage in-wall cabling, including:

Wire the fans to one master switch with compatible multi-way switches in other locations that do not require multi-way wiring.  For example Lutron Companion Switches.  I think there are Z-Wave/Zigbee/etc ones too.
Wire the fans to one smart switch like a GE Cync fan controller and use compatible smart devices, buttons, phones, voice control, etc to operate them from other locations.
put radio fan-control receivers in the fans, or in just one of them with the others wired from it, and use battery-operated transmitters anywhere you want, with one master power switch somewhere out of the way. (If you have one receiver feeding multiple fans, make sure it has the power capacity.)

The examples are not recommendations, I have no relationship, they are only added for clarity.
